# display text into my html text box from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

**Here is my html text for my text-box :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
            <textarea class="form-control3" rows="3" placeholder="Clue 1"></textarea>
            <textarea class="form-control4" rows="3" placeholder="Answer"></textarea>
            <input type="text" class="form-control1" placeholder="10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control2" placeholder="Rejected">
            <div>
                <img src="images/up.png" width="13px" ;height="13px">&nbsp;
                <div class="blank"></div>
                <span class="badge badge-danger">100</span>
                <img src="images/down.png" width="13px" ;height="13px">&nbsp;
                <div class="blank"></div>
                <span class="badge badge-danger">50</span>
                <img src="images/eye.png" width="20px" ;height="20px">
                <div class="blank"></div>
                <span class="badge badge-danger">120</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here is my json code:**
        (This is my .html file)

```
    <html ng-app="myClues">

    <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.9" data-semver="1.3.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("myClues", []);
        app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("new1.json").success(function(result) {
                $scope.Details = result.records;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MyController">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in Details">
                    {{x.Name + ',' + x.City +',' + x.Country}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**(Below is my .json file)**

```
{
  "records": [{
    "Name": "CLUE 1",
    "City": "Answer to clue 1",
    "Country": "10 users rejected"
  }, {
    "Name": "CLUE 2",
    "City": "Answer to clue 2",
    "Country": "5 users rejected"
  }]
}
```

When I run the page I want to display the JSON data in my HTML text boxes which I have created. How do I do that? Is my JSON code correct?

Comment: What do you mean by text box? <textarea>?

Comment: Everything is so messy.. The dataset from your json file can't (or you don't specify how will) be inserted to your "text-box". I don't think anyone can help you the way you describe your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that you're looping over `Details` instead of `Details.records` :

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in Details.records">
             {{x.Name + ',' + x.City +',' + x.Country}}
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: He already uses a ng-repeat. His problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is `ng-repeat="x in Details"`, it should be `ng-repeat="x in Details.records"` (see my example). And I believe "Loretta" is a "she", in doubt, use "they" :)

Comment: Hey Jeremy Thille, thank you for the reply. i am not able to view your example. Have you attached a link? Can you please resend it. I tried Details.records its not working. I am actually new to json. i am not sure about the code i have used is right or wrong. if not my program can you please tell me how to send request to a local json file URL and from another json file url how to use a prefixed data array to update details on the my html page.

Comment: Jeremy by the way, your right. Loretta is a she name.

Comment: Damn, for some reason, I completely missed your `$http` call. You actually store `result.records` in Details. Sorry! Your code should actually work... What if you `console.log(results)` in the `success` function? And try attaching an `.error` function too.

Comment: console.log and console.error functions are not working

Comment: console.log is not working?? What do you mean not working? It's a browser feature, of course it works. About the .error, I was talking about adding an error handler for your $http call : `$http.get(...).success(...).error(function(err){ console.log(err); }` so you can catch and display the error if any.